# How can I determine where my Emacs session is being displayed?

Tags: emacs, ssh, elisp, x11

I often forward my X session from my home server (Slackware) to my work desktop (Cygwin/Windows 7). I.e. `ssh -X home-server; emacs &`. I'd like to know (programmatically) where my Emacs session is being displayed, but the DISPLAY environment isn't very helpful:

```
(getenv "DISPLAY")
"localhost:10.0"
```

Any thoughts?

Update: I should have been more clear; I'm looking for the name of the host on which my X session is runnning (my work desktop, in this case). Calling, say, `(system-name)`, or `(getenv "HOSTNAME")` will return "home-server", where Emacs is actually running.

Update 2: I've been trying to respond to Tobias, below, but trying to get the formatting to work in the comments has been driving me nuts:

Thanks, Tobias, but it seems that `xauth` only deals with authorization data:

```
Using authority file /home/mgh/.Xauthority
home-server/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  c545124...
localhost.localdomain/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  c5451...
home-server/unix:14  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  7b7be...
home-server/unix:13  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  96d13...
home-server/unix:12  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  8b186...
home-server/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  28a0a...
home-server/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  bbf6c...
```

Update 3:

Tobias, it shows this:

```
xauth -v nlist
Using authority file /home/mgh/.Xauthority
0100 0007 4261672d456e64 0001 30 0012 4d49542d4... 0010 c5451248...
0100 0015 6c6f63616c686f73742e6... 0001 30 0012 4d4954... 0010 c545124...
...
0100 0007 4261672d456e64 0002 3130 0012 4d49542d4d... 0010 bbf6c4d...
```

Comment: What does the `display`-item in the result of the function call `(current-frame-configuration)` deliver? Note, that there might be multiple frames on different displays. These would also be listed in the result of `current-frame-configuration`.

Comment: "localhost:10.0"; same as $DISPLAY...

Comment: The display name `localhost:10.0` looks like `xauth -l` (as shell command) should give you the list of xservers. If I understand rightly then `xauth -l localhost:10.0` should give you the direct hit. You can also call this from emacs. The more general case would be `xauth -l "$DISPLAY"`.

Comment: Thanks, Tobias, but it seems that `xauth` only deals with authorization data:

    Using authority file /home/mgh/.Xauthority
    home-server/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  c545124...
    localhost.localdomain/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  c5451...
    home-server/unix:14  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  7b7be...
    home-server/unix:13  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  96d13...
    home-server/unix:12  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  8b186...
    home-server/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  28a0a...
    home-server/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  bbf6c...

Comment: A common arrangement is to have ports set up for each display such that :10.0 corresponds to port 6010. I'm not in a place where I can check if this would actually enable you to trace where the port is connected, and of course, NAT etc could obscure things significantly.

Comment: That's exactly the case, @tripleee. I think that there would need to be some kind of information transmitted from the X-Server at work back to my home server for me to get what I want, here. Parsing out out of the results of `netstat`, e.g., won't work.

Comment: And what does `xauth -n list` say?

Comment: @Tobias, see Update #3 above.

Comment: Sorry for the trial and error. Please, try `xdpyinfo -ext all`. In the output the numeric ip of the display is listed in the form `name of display:    127.0.0.1:0.0`. If you do no have `xdpyinfo` installed it should be available as package (at least it is in cygwin).

Comment: I can imagine that even `xdpyinfo -ext all` will deliver `name of display: 127.0.0.1:10.0`. That would mean that http-requests to the xserver really go to the ssh-mapped xserver. So much to your idea to ask the xserver for the display name.

Comment: Yes, `name of display: localhost:10.0`. I think I see what you're saying: I would need to ask ssh, not X, for this information. Hmph. Well, I can at least get the screen resolution through `xdpyinfo`, which is something.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this on the [Unix stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84848/how-to-find-the-hostname-of-an-x-server).  The short answer is

```
(getenv "SSH_CLIENT")
```

Comment: Yeah... thought of that, but unfortunately in my case, it just tells me the IP address of the DMZ/Firewall/whatever at work, not the address of my actual development box. That's why I think that if the information's available, it's going to have to come over the X protocol, not ssh.

Answer (score 0):

These are just regular linux variables:

```
(getenv "HOSTNAME")
(getenv "TTY")
```

They should give you the machine you are on, and your location on that machine.

Comment: Yes, they'll tell me about the machine on which Emacs is running, but not where it's being displayed. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the X protocol offers a way to ask the X server to give you the hostname of the machine on which it's running.  You might get by with other info, such as the RandR data (whose EDID info might include a brand name of the monitor, for example).